# flow log for specific ENI

Tags: terraform-provider-aws

so I am supposed be able to create a vpc flow log for a specific instance network interface.

I have been able to create a vpc flow log for the entire VPC but not a specific instance network interface.  If I create an instance.  it comes with a eni.  I would think that I should be able to inspect the instance to find the eni and get the eni id.

for  this source code

```
 resource "aws_instance" "master_inst" { ...}

resource "aws_flow_log" "example-instance-flow-log" {
  provider = aws.region_master
  iam_role_arn    = aws_iam_role.master-vpc-flow-log-role.arn
  log_destination = aws_cloudwatch_log_group.master-instance-flow-log.arn
  traffic_type    = "ALL"
  eni_id          = aws_instance.master_inst.network_interface.id
}

resource "aws_cloudwatch_log_group" "master-instance-flow-log" {
  provider = aws.region_master
  name = "master-instance-flow-log"
}
```

I am getting

```
Error: Cannot index a set value
│ 
│   on ../../modules/instances.tf line 78, in resource "aws_flow_log" "example-instance-flow-log":
│   78:   eni_id          = aws_instance.master_inst.network_interface.id
│ 
│ Block type "network_interface" is represented by a set of objects, and set elements do not have addressable keys. To find elements matching specific criteria, use a "for" expression with an "if"
│ clause.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this does the trick
In order for Terraform destroy to clean up the log group the role needs to have permission to destroy the log group.   Now unfortunately adding the delete  to the policy for some reason 1 out of 3 does not actually delete the log group.  so you have to keep the console open to manually delete the log group.

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "flowlog-role" {
  provider = aws.region_master
  name     = "flowlog-role"

  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "vpc-flow-logs.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "flowlog-role-policy" {
  provider = aws.region_master
  name     = "flowlog-role-policy"
  role     = aws_iam_role.flowlog-role.id

  policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": [
        "logs:CreateLogGroup",
        "logs:DeleteLogGroup",
        "logs:CreateLogStream",
        "lots:DeleteLogStream",
        "logs:PutLogEvents",
        "logs:DescribeLogGroups",
        "logs:DescribeLogStreams"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}


resource "aws_cloudwatch_log_group" "master-instance-flowlog-grp" {
  count           = var.enable_instance_flowlog? 1 : 0
  provider          = aws.region_master
  name              = "master-instance-flowlog-grp"
  retention_in_days = 3 ## need to specify number of days otherwise terraform destroy will not remove log group
}

resource "aws_flow_log" "master-instance-flowlog" {
  count           = var.enable_instance_flowlog? 1 : 0
  provider        = aws.region_master
  iam_role_arn    = aws_iam_role.flowlog-role.arn
  log_destination = aws_cloudwatch_log_group.master-instance-flowlog-grp[count.index].arn
  traffic_type    = "ALL"
  eni_id          = aws_instance.master_instance.primary_network_interface_id

}
```